# Android Applications permission access

Tags: android, operating-system

As we  know when an Application installed in android (/system/app folder) , It will assigned a userid and groupid ( that is used in Linux file system)  by system and applications configuration is saved in package.xml . Like file manager application

```
<package name="com.android.filemanager" code Path ="/system/app/  FileManager.apk" flags="1" ts="1314087422000" version="1"  userId="10036">
```

there is no permission tag in this xml . so from where it get execute permission ? .. Is there any methods to get this application permissions .

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions) provides an insight into why it is not possible to get permissions that easily.

Nevertheless, you can use this code in your application to obtain its' permissions dynamically in a List:

```
final List<PackageInfo> permissions_list = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
```

Use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions) attribute of your returned `PackageInfo`s to get a String array of all the permissions declared by `<uses-permission>` tag in manifest, not permissions as you wrote in the comments.

It is also not possible to change those permissions programatically due to security precautions as stated in the documentation link above but there are some applications that allow blocking some permissions for rooted devices. I never used one so I don't know if they work or not.

Comment: @baba_tenor is there any methods to change this permission with root access ?

Comment: and the list that returned the permission list is null for every packages (Permissions_list.permissions return null) . so how do we get dr-r-r in thats pattern nd how to edit it ?

Answer (score 1):

in my case package.xml is there in data/system path it includes all the permissions list with packages

Comment: in that package.xml there is list of permission used in android. manifest file . but i want to know the system permission -w-r-e in this pattern . Please attach a device in  eclipse go to DDMS .. follow the process windows . u can see the permissions there in -r-r-2 in this format . where did this pattern saved